# How to revoke the access using LOOP - redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Team, 
I am using Amazon redshift. below is the version:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.748
```

I would like to drop one user account. if this user has access to any table/schemas/datbase, then that has to be revoked first and then it will allow us to drop the user. In redshift, "drop owned by ;" is not working. so, i need to programatically find out the access to granted to user before dropping it.

for e.g. i am giving access to this user on 2  schemas. But while revoking it, i need to use some FOR ..LOOP and then find out the schemas this user has access and revoke it,  not thro manually ( as below ). Coudl you please help me ? i need to write a small procedure wherein need to create one cursor and store these 2 schemas, and under FOR..loop, i need to call them and revoke them one by one. If you provide this functionality, i can use this to revoke other table grants, database grants etc..

```
redshift=# GRANT all on schema schema44 to proj_user1;
GRANT
redshift=# grant all on schema proj_schema1 to proj_user1;
GRANT
redshift=#
redshift=# select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace where array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%proj_user1%';
   nspname
--------------
 schema44
 proj_schema1
(2 rows)



redshift=# revoke all on schema schema44 from proj_user1;
REVOKE
redshift=# revoke all on schema proj_schema1 from proj_user1;
REVOKE
redshift=# select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace where array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%proj_user1%';
 nspname
---------
(0 rows)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There's no scripting available in Redshift that provides loop functionality.  You can run the queries below from psql and use the output as the script to remove the user.

This query builds the revoke cmds for objects:

```
select  
'revoke ' || substring(
            case when charindex('r',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',select ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('w',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',update ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('a',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',insert ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('d',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',delete ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('R',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',rule ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('x',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',references ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('t',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',trigger ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('X',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',execute ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('T',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl,     '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',temporary ' else '' end 
       , 2,10000)
|| ' on '||namespace||'.'||item ||' from "'||pu.usename||'";' as grantsql
from 
(SELECT 
 use.usename as subject, 
 nsp.nspname as namespace, 
 c.relname as item, 
 c.relkind as type, 
 use2.usename as owner, 
 c.relacl 
FROM 
 pg_user use 
 cross join pg_class c 
 left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
 left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
WHERE 
c.relowner = use.usesysid  
and  nsp.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY 
subject,   namespace,   item 
) join pg_user pu on array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%'||pu.usename||'%' 
where relacl is not null
 and pu.usename='<username>'
order by 1;
```

Then you will need to change any table ownerships:

```
select 'alter table '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||' owner to <newowner>;' from pg_tables where tableowner = '<username>';
```

You can't change ownerships of views, so you have to drop them:

```
select 'drop view '||schemaname||'.'||viewname||' ;' from pg_views where viewowner = '<username>';
```

You'll need to remove the user from any groups:

```
select 'alter group '||nvl(groname,'default')||' drop user '||usename||';' from pg_user u left join pg_group g on ','||array_to_string(grolist,',')||',' like '%,'||cast(usesysid as varchar(10))||',%' where usename='<username>' ;
```

Finally remove from schemas:

```
select 
'revoke ' || substring(
          case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
       , 2,10000)
|| ' on schema '||nspname||' from "'||pu.usename||'";' 
from pg_namespace pn,pg_user pu
 where pu.usename='<username>' and array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%'||pu.usename||'%'
 and nspowner > 1 ;
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. If this user has access on any other database, then I need to revoke it (mynewdb1=# revoke all on database mynewdb1 from test_4;). but I am still able to connect this db( mynewdb1 ) as TEST_4. ( note: i removed from public also, h'ever it happens in redshift ). any alternate ?

Comment: So you don't want to drop the user, but just disable them from connecting?  I'm not certain, but I think the only alternative is to drop them.